# Search method that returns all the positions of an object in an array -Java

Tags: java, arrays, object, search

Card is an object and deck is an array that holds those cards. I'm trying to find all the positions of a given card object in the deck and store all those in a new array and then return that new array.

My current search method looks like this:

```
public int[] search(Card c)
{
    int length = 0;
    for (int x = 0 ; x < deck.length ; x++) // look through an array
    {
        if (deck[x].equals(c)) // value found in the array
        {
        length++; //update length
        }
    }

    int[] temp = new int[length]; //create new int array with that length
    for (int x = 0 ; x < deck.length ; x++) // look through the old array again
    {
        if (deck[x].equals(c)) // value found in that array
        {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < temp.length ; y++) //go through new array
            {
               temp[y] = x+1; //add the position to new array
            }
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
int[] pos = deck.search (Deck.deck[11]); //search for 11th card in deck
//display the position
System.out.println("The Card is in position:" + Arrays.toString(pos));
```

Although this code returns an array of the proper length, it fills up each and every slot with the position of the last occurrence of the value. (Note: I'm not using ArrayList)

**UPDATE: The issue was resolved after taking out the for-loop that updates y and instead making y a variable which updates every time the cards match (in the second loop).**

Thanks for mentioning the equals() method guys!

Comment: try using a debugger

Comment: `if (deck[x] == c)` - does your `Card` object has an overridden `equals` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using == to compare objects can be dangerous if both objects occupy different memory locations, but have the same content (ie. Queen of hearts) because using == compares both objects memory locations. You should override the .equals() method in Card and instead use `if(deck[x].equals(c))...`

[Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html) is a good article discussing why .equals is important

And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) is the documentation for the equals method in the object class

Comment: Even after I used equals, it gives the same output :C

Comment: Have you tried running the debugger line by line? Sometimes when I make a careless mistake, seeing the variables update in real time helps me see my issue.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll do that C: